# Flask Filter Drop Down Not Returning Data

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, dropdown

I am developing a Flask solution for the user to filter the items in a table using a drop down select list. The first page is a simple drop down list, from which the user selects a category. Upon hitting the enter button, the results page is rendered, with the list of all of the rows of the table where the category is the one selected by the user.

I do not receive any error messages, however, the results page only comes with the column headings -- no data is returned.

As this is a simple drop down box filter, I would think there would be a simple solution to this situation. I searched for relevant solutions within StackOverflow, but all of the other solutions were for much more complex situations that did not seem to be completely relevant to what I am trying to accomplish.

Here is the code I tried to implement my task:

```
@app.route('/search3')
def search3():
    category = request.args.get('category', '')
    query = Profile.query
    if category:
        query = query.filter_by(category=category)
    profiles = query.all()
    return render_template('search3.html', **locals())

@app.route('/results')
def results():
    
    return render_template('results.html')
```

Here are the relevant parts of my code.
Here is the table layout:

```
# Models
class Profile(db.Model):
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    merchant = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    cMerchantOther = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=False, nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    drcr = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    category = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    pmtmethod = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    updated = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Category : {self.category}, Price: {self.price}"
```

Here is the HTML page where the user selects the category by which to filter (search3.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'style/style1.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label>Select a Category</label>
        <select name="category">
            <option value>Select a category</option>
            {% for value in ('Kitchen', 'Pay', 'Medical', 'Food',) -%}
            <option value="{{ value }}" {% if value == category %}selected{% endif %}>{{ value }}</option>
            {% endfor -%}
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
```

Here is the code for the results page (results.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Search Results</title>
  
    <link href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'style/style1.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Merchant</th>
            <th>Other</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>DrCr</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Payment Method</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>#</th>
        </thead>
        {% for data in ProfileSearch %}
        <tbody>
            <td>{{data.id}}</td>
            <td>{{data.merchant}}</td>
            <td>{{data.cMerchantOther}}</td>
            <td>{{data.price}}</td>
            <td>{{data.drcr}}</td>
            <td>{{data.category}}</td>
            <td>{{data.pmtmethod}}</td>
            <td>{{data.updated}}</td>
            <td><a href="/delete/{{data.id}}" type="button">Delete</a></td>
        </tbody>
        {% endfor%}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide a clear `method` attribute to submit the form. Either GET or POST should be specified. If nothing is specified, GET is chosen. However, by querying `request.form` you expect an input via POST, which does not exist.

The following example sends the form data via GET. The optional input sent as URL parameters is requested using `request.args`.

```py
@app.route('/search')
def search():
    category = request.args.get('category', '')
    query = Profile.query
    if category:
        query = query.filter_by(category=category)
    profiles = query.all()
    return render_template('search.html', **locals())
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label>Select a Category</label>
        <select name="category">
            <option value>Select a category</option>
            {% for value in ('Kitchen', 'Pay', 'Medical', 'Food',) -%}
            <option value="{{ value }}" {% if value == category %}selected{% endif %}>{{ value }}</option>
            {% endfor -%}
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Merchant</th>
                <th>Other</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>DrCr</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Payment Method</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>#</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for data in profiles -%}
            <tr>
                <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                <td>{{data.merchant}}</td>
                <td>{{data.cMerchantOther}}</td>
                <td>{{data.price}}</td>
                <td>{{data.drcr}}</td>
                <td>{{data.category}}</td>
                <td>{{data.pmtmethod}}</td>
                <td>{{data.updated}}</td>
                <td><a href="/delete/{{data.id}}" type="button">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor -%}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

If you want to use a POST request and present the results on another page, the following code is a possible solution. In this case, post is defined as a method and a separate route is declared to receive the data.

```py
@app.route('/search')
def index():
    return render_template('search.html')

@app.post('/results')
def results():
    category = request.form.get('category', '')
    query = Profile.query
    if category:
        query = query.filter_by(category=category)
    profiles = query.all()
    return render_template('results.html', **locals())
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'style/style1.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ url_for('.results') }}" method="post">
        <label>Select a Category</label>
        <select name="category">
            <option value>Choose one</option>
            {% for value in ('Kitchen', 'Pay', 'Medical', 'Food',) -%}
            <option value="{{ value }}">{{ value }}</option>
            {% endfor -%}
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Search Results</title>
    <link href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'style/style1.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Merchant</th>
                <th>Other</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>DrCr</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Payment Method</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>#</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for data in profiles %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                <td>{{data.merchant}}</td>
                <td>{{data.cMerchantOther}}</td>
                <td>{{data.price}}</td>
                <td>{{data.drcr}}</td>
                <td>{{data.category}}</td>
                <td>{{data.pmtmethod}}</td>
                <td>{{data.updated}}</td>
                <td><a href="/delete/{{data.id}}" type="button">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor%}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to provide that detailed response to my question, Detlef. I tried to implement your solution, but when I submit the form, it just reverts right back to the search page, with  "search3?category= " appended to the url. I have edited the original post to include the revised code. I suppose my sticking point at this point, is how to render the results template, in the same app.route that I use to launch the search form? I want the user to be able to click on a link to get to the search form, and after selecting a category, to be redirected to the results form.

Comment: @RockyN I've expanded my answer. With a GET request, the entries are added to the URL as parameters. With a POST request, the data is sent in the request body, invisible to third parties. Both options are open to you. The option to link to a results page is possible for both variants, but not absolutely necessary.

Comment: it worked!  Thank you so much for your help! I have been trying to figure this out for weeks, looking through this site, and other programming sites, but coming up empty. I would give you an upvote, but I am new to this site and have not yet earned the privilege of upvoting.

Comment: You don't need to upvote. If the answer meets your requirements, simply click the check mark to accept the answer.